# How to add one more button in Fragments

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, android-activity

I have given the code i worked out and it works fine but i dont no how to add one more button to redirect to another activity

```
public class courses extends Fragment  {

    Intent intent;


    @Nullable
    @Override


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courses, container, false);
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), software_course.class);
        final Button button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.Software_Course);



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return root; 
     } }
```

Comment: add it in `courses.xml` and inflate it in fragment as you did with button.

Comment: just add another button same as Software_Course button is added in courses.xml , just remember to give different id to it, and refer it in  onCreateView same as Software_Course is initialized and add clickListener

Comment: I did as you said but it shows " Variable 'button' is already defined in the scope this is what i did @AndroidWeblineindia

 View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courses, container, false);
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), hardware_course.class);
        final Button button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.Hardware_Course);

Comment: just give the different variable name as 'button' is already used by Software_Course Button so you can give like 'button1' for Hardware_Course,  like final Button button1 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.Hardware_Course);

Comment: in xml side everthing is ready a button with the attributes Id(Hardware_Course) and onClick(hc), I dont know how to call it to the java side of the program @Shvet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only some tips before the real answer:

- Use first capitalized letter for classes' name
- Don't use first capitalized letter for ids
- Don't create differents new OnClickListener instance as below, instead implement the interface
- The global intent variable hasn't a lot of sense

Now here is the 'rapid' answer:

```
public class Courses extends Fragment {
    Intent intent, anotherIntent;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courses, container, false);
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Software_course.class);
        anotherIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourSecondActivityName.class);
        final Button button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.software_Course);
        final Button button2 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.software_Course2);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(anotherIntent);
            }
        });

        return root; 
    }
}
```

Here is what I recommend:

```
public class Courses extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {    
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courses, container, false);
        root.findViewById(R.id.software_Course).setOnClickListener(this);
        root.findViewById(R.id.software_Course2).setOnClickListener(this);         

        return root; 
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.software_Course:
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Software_course.class));
                break;
            case R.id.software_Course2:
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), YourSecondActivityName.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code  Worked, Its Simple and Its Easy.Thankyou specially for giving the most valuable tips for a starter like me @Fondesa

Comment: as said I am a starter I dont have enof reputation in stackoverflow as soon as i get three more reputation i will surely do it...

Answer (score 1):

In your `courses.xml` add One more button with different id of other button.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/hardware"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In your `courses.java` initialize button and use `setonClickListener`.

```
public class courses extends Fragment  {

    Intent intent;


    @Nullable
    @Override


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courses, container, false);
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), software_course.class);
    final Button button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.Software_Course);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button Hardware=(Button)root.findViewById(R.id.Hardware_Course);
    Hardware.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do stuff you want to do on click of button
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), hardware_course.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

return root;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks the code worked like a charm after making some small edits.Hope you wont mind because I just edited yor code.. @Shvet